# MYSQL employee and dependent

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL using MYSQL and as a practice I want to get the name of employees who has a dependent whose first letter of his/her name matches the middle name of that employee. Also they must be of same gender. Here is how I have done it so far:

```
SELECT
e.fname
, e.minit
, e.lname
FROM
employee e
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM dependent WHERE e.ssn=essn AND e.sex=sex)
```

Now, am I supposed to use LIKE or what? I am not sure how to make that middle name match work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
 e.fname
 e.minit
 , e.lname
 , dependent_name
 FROM employee AS e 
 INNER JOIN
 dependent
 ON SUBSTRING(e.minit,1,1) = SUBSTRING(dependent_name,1,1) AND  
 e.sex=dependent.sex AND essn=e.ssn
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select e.fname, e.minit, e.lname, d.name
from employee e
inner join dependent d on e.substring(e.minit, 1, 1) = substring(d.name, 1, 1) 
                       and e.sex = d.sex
```

Comment: Well, I wanted first letter of dependent's name to match the middle name of the employee, but you have done the opposite. Still I am appreciated, I researched on substring a bit and corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.fname, e.minit, e.lname, d.mname  
FROM employee AS e 
JOIN
dependent AS d
ON SUBSTRING(e.fname,1,1) = SUBSTRING(d.mname,1,1) AND e.sex = d.sex;
```

Comment: Well, I wanted first letter of dependent's name to match the middle name of the employee, but you have done the opposite. Still I am appreciated, I researched on substring a bit and corrected it.